# XPath search using operators

Tags: objective-c, parsing, ios4, xpath, xml-parsing

Hi i have the following code that searches for and retrieves the first paragraph after `<h3>`

```
//div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]/h3[.='Course Content']/following-sibling::p[1]
```

Because i'm using the same code on multiple web pages, some of those pages do not contain `<h3>` and instead contain `<h4>` tag. What is the syntax to check if there is a `<h3>` tag and if not check for `<h4>`?

Comment: You mean: check if child element exists?

Comment: "some of those pages do not contain...." what?

Comment: 'Course Content' is either written using a <h3> or <h4> tag. I would like to know how check for the 'either' if the first tag does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if child element exists using predicate, e.g.:

```
//div[span]
```

It will select all `div` elements which have `span`

```
//div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]/*[self::h3 or self::h4 and .='Course Content']/following-sibling::p[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XPath 2.0 then you can replace `h3` by `(h3|h4)`.

In XPath 1.0 you'll need to replace it by `*[self::h3 or self::h4]`